# trouble passing arguments from function to function python

Tags: python-3.x

i must be doing something wrong but i can't seem to to figure it out.  I'm try to pass arguments from one function to another but in my passing i keep getting "something is undefined" and i can't figure out how to fix it.

```
def Information():
    #for x in range(0,3):
        #if x==0:
        #    print("first user")
        #elif x==1:
        #    print("Second user")
        #elif x==2:
        #    print("Third user")

        age=int(input("Please enter your age: "))
        height=int(input("Please enter your height in inches: "))
        eye=input("Please enter your eye color: ")
        First=input("Please enter your first name: ")
        Last=input("Please enter your last name: ")
        Street=input("Please enter your street address: ")
        City=input("Please enter your city: ")
        State=input("Please enter your state: ")
        Zip=int(input("Please enter your zip code: "))
        Infile=open('DataFile1.txt', 'a')
        Infile.write(str(age)+'\n')
        Infile.write(str(height)+'\n')
        Infile.write(eye+'\n')
        Infile.write(First+'\n')
        Infile.write(Last+'\n')
        Infile.write(str(Street)+'\n')
        Infile.write(City+'\n')
        Infile.write(State+'\n')        
        Infile.write(str(Zip)+'\n')
        Infile.close()                    
def Duplicate():
        info=[]
        with open("DataFile1.txt") as infile:
            for line in infile:
                    info.append(line)
        print(info)
        age2 = info[0]
        height2 = info[1]
        eye_color2 = info[2]
        first_name2 = info[3]
        last_name2 = info[4]
        street_address2 = info[5]
        city2 = info[6]
        state2 = info[7]
        zip_code2 = info[8]    
        return(age2,height2,eye_color2,first_name2,last_name2,street_address2,state2,zip_code2)
def Print(age,height,eye_color,first_name,last_name,street_address,city,state,zip_code):
        print(last_name, first_name)
        print(street_address)
        print(city, state, zip_code)
        print('Age: ', age)
        print('Height: ', height)
        print('Eye Color: ', eye_color)
def Main():
    Information()
    Duplicate()
    Print(age,height,eye_color,first_name,last_name,street_address,city,state,zip_code)


Main()
```

Comment: The returned value of Duplicate() must be send to some variable.

Comment: if i send it to a variable how will i be able to print it out in my second function that uses it in the format that its typed in? do now i have it set as Duplicate(thing) and i receive and error that its missing a required argument.

Answer (score 0):

In the `Main()` function, the variables in Print() is not defined. The following code will do the magic.

```
args = Duplicate()
Print(*args)
```

Comment: does that args = Duplicate() go in my main function or in the Duplicate function? I added it to the main function and receive  line 61, in Main
    print(*args)
TypeError: print() argument after * must be a sequence, not function
well i had a typo fixed that and it worked like a champ

Comment: but now is it possible to make it print out in such a way that someone would know what the numbers are?? example print('Age: ',age),

Comment: @shadow That is because you forget to return city2 in the last line in Print() function.

Comment: so if i use my Print function do i still need the args = Duplicate?     I went back to my original program without out it and get and error "Print missing 9 required positional arguments"

Comment: so even with passing ,y print function the 9 arguments that my Duplicate function returns i get the error that age2 is undefined